# Browser locale in struts2 using Java

Tags: java, struts2

How do we detect browser locale in struts2? I've language drop-down in website. Now, how to detect what language user ha selected in Struts2?

I've loginaction.java which extends AwareBaseAction, how can I detect user browser locale in loginaction.java?

Any sample code in Java is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [localization docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/localization.html) cover the different ways to process language selection. (See also the [I18N interceptor page](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/i18n-interceptor.html) and [How do we change locales FAQ entry](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-do-we-change-locales.html).)

In addition, you can access the request's local via the standard [getLocale()/getLocales() methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale%28%29) and process them differently if necessary.